# Get time in comment or post in android

Tags: android, android-activity

How to get time in any post to show how much time has been gone doing this post.
For example in facebook you see the time which is passed  away after your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        Date past = format.parse("20/08/2015 18:10:52");
        Date now = new Date();
        System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " seconds ago");
        System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " minutes ago");
        System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " hours ago");
        System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " days ago");
```

Comment: please check the error 

                                     08-28 10:47:08.095: W/System.err(3151): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-08-04 06:37:27" (at offset 4)
08-28 10:47:08.095: W/System.err(3151):  at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626)
08-28 10:47:08.099: W/System.err(3151):  at com.pankaj.taughtable.Teaching.onCreate(Teaching.java:56)
08-28 10:47:08.099: W/System.err(3151):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
08-28 10:47:08.099: W/System.err(3151):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)

Comment: your date consist '-' while in simpleDateFormat object its '/', both format should be same

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about what you mean, giving more details would probably help.
If you want to have something like "Posted 10minutes ago", I guess you'd have to store the date/hour of the post. Then when displaying it, doing a simple operation : Time = CurrentTime - PostTime

Let's say you post something at 12:00.
You store the post with the hour
When displaying (at 12:10 for example), you substract the posted hour from the actual hour, and tchiiiing ! "Posted 10 mins ago"

You'll also have to get some work to display a difference between seconds, minutes, hours and day, but basically that's how it would work !